# How to use symfony dom parser

Tags: php, symfony, dom, domcrawler

I am trying to use Symfony Crawler.

So I have checked this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

What I want to do is to get the `3,335.00`(The second argument)

For now, I try sentence like this, but it is wrong.

`$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > div[@class="cell_label"]');`

How can I do it??

```
<body>
<div class="cell__label">  Value1  </div> <div class="cell__value cell__value_"> 2,355.00 </div>
<div class="cell__label">  Value2  </div> <div class="cell__value cell__value_"> 3,355.00 </div>
<div class="cell__label">  Value3  </div> <div class="cell__value cell__value_"> 4,355.00 </div>
</body>

$crawler = new Crawler($url);
$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > div[@class="cell_label"]');//// no work...

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    var_dump($domElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several issue here:

1. Using [`$crawler->filter()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_filter) implies you must pass a css selector as a parameter, not XPath expressions, so use `'body > div.cell__label'` or `'body div[class^="cell__"]'` if you need to select all `div` with a class that starts with `cell__`, btw you have a typo in `cell_label` (one underscore).
2. The Crawler [accepts](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_add) <kbd>DOMNodeList</kbd>, <kbd>DOMNode</kbd>, <kbd>array</kbd> or <kbd>string</kbd> as a constructor parameters, not a url to a remote resource (but I assume it may be just an arbitrary variable name you used there). Technically url is a string as well, but not XML formatted string.
3. If you want to use XPath expression use [`$crawler->filterXPath()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_filterXPath), like that:

   `$nodes = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[contains(@class, "cell__label")]');`

Here's a documentation on how to use XPath - https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: THank you this quite helps. And as you mentioned. I wrongly used about `$url`. I use not `$url` but `$html` after `$html = @file_get_contents($url);`

Answer (score 0):

Crawler filter can handle jQuery like selectors, so you can:

`$crawler = $crawler->filter('.cell__value');`